# Date comparison doesn't take year into account

Tags: sql-server, date, format, comparison, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to retrieve records by comparing date values as follows :

```
declare @fromdate as date
declare @todate as date
set @fromdate='2013-04-01'
set @todate='2013-04-13'
select createdon,
convert(varchar,PhoneCall.createdon,101) as createdon,
convert(varchar,@fromdate,101) as fromdate
from
PhoneCall
where convert(varchar,PhoneCall.createdon,101)  >= convert(varchar,@fromdate,101) and  convert(varchar,PhoneCall.createdon,101)  <= convert(varchar,@todate,101)
```

There is something wrong in the comparison, I've tried using various conversion formats but I'm not receiving correct results.

The query above has been my latest trial, although it looks correct, **it doesn't take into account the comparison of the Year**. So the results displayed are as follows:

```
      Createdon            ConvertedCreatedOn      ConvertedFromDate  
2013-05-08 14:13:16.000      05/08/2013              05/01/2013
2014-05-01 17:10:03.000      05/01/2014              05/01/2013
```

EDIT: 
This is a query I'll use for a report. The @fromdate and @todate are report parameters that will be entered manually by the user, so I have to make sure that they're in the same format with the database date format.

Comment: you need to use the filtered views instead the table, so use FilteredPhoneCall instead of PhoneCall

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this. I read more on the Views and I realized i should be using them, this is a good link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2006/05/01/587823.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you convert all DATE fields/params to VARCHAR? Just use DATE comparison:

```
where PhoneCall.createdon BETWEEN @fromdate AND @todate
```

IF you NEED to use varchar then you should use [102 format (yyyy.mm.dd)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) instead of 101 (mm/dd/yyyy). In this case it can be used to compare dates as strings.

Comment: Thank you very much, that saved me hours of trials. But is there any reason why "101" doesn't work ? I mean isn't it about having the same format on both sides then the comparison should work out ? I'm not sure if I should create another question for this

Comment: @user3340627: After you convert dates to VARCHAR you get two STRINGS and compare them with STRING comparison rules. It starts from the first letter and goes to the first difference to decide which one have to be first in order. If you use 101 format (DD.MM.YYYY) then DAY is a fist element so `02.MM.YYYY` is ALWAYS `>= 01.MM.YYYY` for any month and year.